# Why does $\arg (f \circ \gamma)' (t_0) = \arg (f'(z_0)) + \arg (\gamma' (t_0))\ $?

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation, conformal-geometry

[image]

Can anybody help me understanding as to why $\arg (f \circ \gamma)' (t_0) = \arg (f'(z_0)) + \arg (\gamma' (t_0)) $ holds?

I know that $\arg (z_1z_2) \neq \arg (z_1) + \arg (z_2)$ unless $-\pi \lt \arg (z_ 1) + \arg (z_2) \leq \pi.$

How do I make sure that $\arg (f'(z_0)) + \arg (\gamma'(t_0)) \in (-\pi, \pi]\ $? Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Complex analysis is full of flaws. It's a worthless subject. Everytime I read it, it creates trouble.

Comment: Don't be like [the fox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fox_and_the_Grapes#:~:text=The%20story%20concerns%20a%20fox,grapes%22%20originated%20from%20this%20fable.) Anyway, you should forget about the term "multivalued function", this is a completely contradictory term when used with modern definitions. The argument function $\text{Arg}$ is a well-defined map from $\Bbb{C}\setminus\{0\} \to \Bbb{R}/2\pi\Bbb{Z}$. i.e the target space of the function is not $\Bbb{R}$, but rather the quotient space $\Bbb{R}/2\pi\Bbb{Z}$ (this is what people mean when they say "multi-valued function")

Comment: For every non-zero complex number $z$, there is a unique number $\alpha(z)\in (-\pi,\pi]$ such that $\frac{z}{|z|} = e^{i\alpha(z)}$. But, if you let $\text{arg}(z):= [\alpha(z)]$ be the equivalence class modulo $2\pi$, then the nice rules hold, that $\text{arg}(z_1z_2) = \text{arg}(z_1) + \text{arg}(z_2)$ (the addition on the RHS being the one on the space $\Bbb{R}/2\pi \Bbb{Z}$)

Comment: @user580918 I am studying Conway's complex analysis in which there is not a single word along your lines. Don't know where do you get this.

Comment: You misinterpreted my intention: I meant to say that you should just ask more questions (and keep asking good questions like you have been doing so far) to clarify your doubts rather than dismissing an entire subject as being "worthless" and being "full of flaws". If you found that reference offensive I apologise. Take a look at Henri Cartan's complex analysis text Chapter 1.3.4 "Measurement of Angles, Argument of a Complex Number". In general, "multi-valued function" really just means "set-valued function", or that elements of the target space  are themselves sets.

Comment: Complex analysis is a domain that has taken time to be settled on firm bases. It is sometimes even paradoxical, these bases can look shaky, with traps for the newcomer and even for the old beards (but no more than in real analysis...) but how subtle, how rewarding !

Comment: Why the downvote? This is called "Nepotism".If somebody wants to learn from the fundamental point of view, he/she gets downvoted in this site. The answerer with higher reputation will always be upvoted even if he/she fails to provide essential details in the answer to suit lower reputated OP's purpose. "Nepotism" and "Biasedness" at it's pick. Keep up the good work "Moderators". Hats of to you! What a ridiculous site it is!

Answer (score 1):

Use the formula for the derivative of the composition of two functions:

$$(f \circ \gamma)' (t_0) = f'(z_0)\gamma' (t_0)$$

then, take the argument of both sides:

$$\arg (f \circ \gamma)' (t_0) = \arg (f'(z_0)) + \arg (\gamma' (t_0))$$

Comment: I already know what you wrote. Read my question carefully and then answer. My problem lies in the last equality what you wrote. That's what I have also mentioned at the fag end. Can we always say that $$\arg (z_1z_2) = \arg (z_1) + \arg (z_2),\ \text {for any}\ z_1,z_2 \in \Bbb C\ ?$$

Comment: The argument of the product of two complex numbers is the sum of their arguments just because $r_1e^{i \theta_1}r_2e^{i \theta_2}=r_1r_2e^{i (\theta_1+\theta_2)}$,

Comment: No. It's not correct. Here $\arg z$ denotes the principal argument of $z,$ not the multivalued argument. Here $\arg z \in (-\pi,\pi].$

Comment: How do you ascertain whether $\theta_1 + \theta_2 \in (-\pi,\pi]$ even if both $\theta_1, \theta_2 \in (-\pi, \pi]\ $? For instantce take $z_1 = -1$ and $z_2 = i.$ What is $\arg (z_1 z_2)\ $? Is it $\arg (z_1) + \arg (z_2)\ $?

Comment: I don't see the harm to consider multivalued argument (i.e., mod $2 \pi$) : it is what I meant.

Comment: multivalued argument is not a function. Can we able to consider it?

Comment: Then the angle preserving criterion stated in the conformality doesn't make much of sense. Because the angle between two vectors is not given by the multivalued argument in an well defined way.

Comment: But if you work in a small vicinity of $z_0$, you can consider to be in a well-defined "sheet" (in the sense of Riemann surface) of multivalued function "arg"

Comment: I don't know what Riemann surfaces are. It was not taught in our coursework. By the way what do you mean by "small vicinity"?

Comment: What properties of $f$ leads to that conclusion? Nobody clears those things.

Comment: "Small vicinity" is a precise term of topology ; but I could have said "a small enough open disc centered in $z_0$". About Riemann surfaces, see for example http://kandy.visitors.sk/clanky/valikova_dissertation.pdf, see for example fig 2.11 p. 29 and the nicely colored figures you will find in its Chapter 3. I will stop there.